# Error Handling in golang

Tags: go

I need to handle errors with error code and return errors in JSON format like below.

```
{
    "errorCode":400,
    "errors":[
        {
            "errorField":"dispachNumber",
            "errorDescription": "This is not a valid dispatch Number"
        },
        {
            "errorField":"phone",
            "errorDescription": "Phone numbers must be in the XXX-XXX-XXXX format"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "errorCode":500,
    "errors":[
        {
            "errorDescription": "there was an internal server error"
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is how to handle this way , here i am able to do with single error only but when i do with multiple errors it return only one error struct , see code how i am doing this.

```
Errors := ErrorHandle(403, "User Id", "User Id must be of integer type")
Errors = ErrorHandle(403, "Phone Number", "Phone Number type")
```

and `ErrorHandle()` function as

```
func ErrorHandle(ErrorCode int, ErrorFields, ErrorDesc string) []Errors {
    AllErrors := []Errors{}

    if len(AllErrors) > 0 {
        AllErrors = IterateErrors(AllErrors, ErrorCode, ErrorFields, ErrorDesc)
    } else {
        Errorsvalue := Errors{
            ErrorCode: ErrorCode,
        }
        Error := Error{}
        Error.ErrorFields = ErrorFields
        Error.ErrorDescription = ErrorDesc
        Errorsvalue.ErrorDesc = append(Errorsvalue.ErrorDesc, Error)

        AllErrors = append(AllErrors, Errorsvalue)
    }
    return AllErrors
}
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: By the looks of things, `AllErrors` is a variable local to `ErrorHandle` and you're initializing it to an empty slice each time you enter `ErrorHandle`.

Comment: @Michael i used `AllErrors` as global variable and its working well but it could be generate unexpected result when multiple user request for same URL, how to fix these issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always creating a new empty `AllErrors` slice, adding a single error to it, then returning it.

Your `ErrorHandle` should either take the existing list of errors and append to it or you should have a custom `type Errors []Error` used as such:

```
type Errors []Error
func (Errors *e) ErrorHandle(...) {
  ...
  e = append(e, <new error>)
}

Errors myerrors;
myerrors.ErrorHandle(<first error>)
myerrors.ErrorHandle(<second error>)
```

This is just high-level code, you should be able to fill in the rest.

Comment: Thanks for reply its working but need to append Error Field And Desc as per Error code. suppose in Errors already has one errors with 403 then another error occurred with same error code(403) then i have to add only Error Field and Desc with respect to Error Code.

Comment: Then you can manipulate the existing errors. The overall problem with your code is that you're returning a new slice every time. You need to modify the existing one instead.

Comment: parse the json object into an interface and then get underlying value of that interface to check if error code already exists. By this way you can update your existing slice of error with new error field